# Using arrays in cpp boost library

Tags: c++, boost

I have just started using the boost library and need to use a boost::array. I want the size of this array N,  to depend on the size of some matrix that I will load into the program.

I find that if I predefine the size, i.e I know the matrix is of size 10 then

```
const int N = 10; 
typedef std::pair<int,int> Edge; 
array<Edge,N> edges;
```

works and I can use the array `edges` as I choose. However if I don't explicity say `const int N =10` but instead have N depending on something such as `const int N =b` where b is some integer then I get an error `'N' cannot appear in constant-expression`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where does `b` come from?

Comment: You can't use `boost::array` without a size known at compile time. It looks like you need to use a different container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boost::array` cannot be sized dynamically, it's specific purpose is for a fixed size array.

You can use a `std::vector` instead if you want to size it during runtime.

Two `boost::array` with the same type but different sizes are different kinds of objects and incompatible with each other.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll switch to vectors instead.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::array` and template parameters in general require constant expressions as arguments. This is because templates are evaluated at compile time not runtime.

If you need a runtime dynamic array, then `std::vector` is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll switch to vectors instead.